# Magento refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: magento, xampp

I just did a fresh install of Magento2 (with composer) on Xammp and ran into this error while loading up the admin page:

[image: Magento Error]

I'm on windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit, Xammp v7.2.12

tried this solution, but did not work:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144143/mime-type-text-html-is-not-executable-and-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabl?noredirect=1&lq=1

What is a solution to this type of error in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to provide more information in order to help you.

1. Do you have other working Magento 2 instances on the same XAMPP setup or is it your first and only one instance?
2. How does the virtual host file ( located in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\ ) looks like? Do you include multiple vhost files for localhost?
3. Can you see any warning or error in C:/xampp/apache/logs/error/* while loading the admin page?

I am not sure if it could be related to your BaseURL ( localhost ) or simply a misconfiguration in your virtual host file. I your case I would probably setup an isolated virtual host file for http://magento-test-ground.local instead http://localhost/magento-test-groud

For example: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155227/magento-2-multiple-website-setup-in-localhost